# Can I pass in a value via props which does not exist in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In Reactjs, let's say I have a `<Parent>` component with state and a 'global' (or local to Parent) variable named `foo`.

Is it possible to pass `foo` as props like `<Child value={foo}>` and trigger a component update on `<Child>` when `foo` updates? Remembering that `foo` is simply a variable and not state, but is modified from within the Parent component.

It seems to me that React will only consider re-rendering when it sees a call to `this.setState({...});` and so `<Child>` would never even know about a props change until that was called.

Comment: React will update the child component when the parent re-renders.  So yes you're right, you have to have something that tells the component to re-render - this is either done by updating it's state or by passing new props.  So if you get your parent component to re-render by changing its state then pass something from its state to the child as a prop, that'll cause the child to update the prop.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, using a variable `foo` which changes as the `Parent` component changes will work the same as using a `state` variable, if you can get `Parent` to rerender without `setState()`, as you mentioned.

However, perhaps React uses a data signing mechanism for it's DOM comparison checks (the thing that makes sure only what's updated gets changed in the actual DOM) that relies on the `state`, causing a rerender on `Child` components regardless of if `foo` changed. (All in giant parentheses as it's just a little thought I had)

But `foo` sounds exactly like the kind of variable that should be put in the `state`, why not just put it there? In the React docs there's a page explaining what to put in the state. I'll grab it's link in a few minutes.

---

**Edit:** As per your comment, to create a situation where several components receive some data, you can easily use Flux architecture.

With React, you can use Alt. I found it to be easy and intuitive - you create an action and bind listeners on your React components, these will be invoked when your action is called. You can use a store if you want, that will be your "single source of truth" regarding your piece of data. The React components can either listen to actions or to changes in the store. (And you bind methods on your store to your action).

Try [this tutorial](http://sahatyalkabov.com/create-a-character-voting-app-using-react-nodejs-mongodb-and-socketio/), I found it very thorough and easy, also visit [Alt docs](http://alt.js.org/guide/).

Comment: I suppose what I'm trying to achieve is a notification system which is wrapped in some kind of abstraction. I have multiple components which need to be able to do 'notifications.push("blah")' for example and would like to not have to repeatedly write functions to call setState in each component that uses notifactions. My gut tells me Flux is a way to do this but I haven't got my head around it yet.

Comment: Flux is definitely the way to go. I recommend using Alt as it is highly compatible with React. Try [this tutorial](http://sahatyalkabov.com/create-a-character-voting-app-using-react-nodejs-mongodb-and-socketio/), I found it very thorough and easy, also visit [Alt docs](http://alt.js.org/guide/).

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this in my own code, I tried using this.hello and setting it to 'HELLO', I then modified it in componentDidMount to 'NOTHELLO' and put the variable into a div in my render. The variable will not change from 'HELLO' to 'NOTHELLO' until I trigger a setState somewhere else. So, react will not update a variable that is not in the state or props because it's not rendering again.
Why not add it to your state? If it's used at a higher level than the  just pass it down through props and update it through callbacks instead of using state.

Comment: Well of course it doesn't.  You need to make React re-render to pick up the changes, right now a render call won't occur because you've not told it to.  Renders will occur on mount and then on any changes to state (setState,forceUpdate,replaceState) AND when receiving incoming props, for example from another React.render call or a parent component rendering again.

Comment: apologies, i think this was a pretty strange question in general

Comment: Yes, I understand this. I explained everything in your comment in my answer, which was a response to the OP's question. Please do not suggest people to use forceUpdate or replaceState as they are either no longer supported or are not recommended and break away from the React methodology.
I just deleted my other comment because I hit Save Edits before finishing.

Comment: yeah I wasn't suggesting using them, just listing things that cause component re-renders.  Also as far as I'm aware only `replaceState` is deprecated in 0.14.

Comment: Yeah you're correct, forceUpdate is still available but I know it's frowned upon. I wouldn't be surprised to see it deprecated in 0.15 or sometime relatively soon.